# How to calculate a float number with given decimal places?

Tags: go

I need an algorithm to calculate a float number given an int number and the decimal places.

Here are a couple of examples to understand what I mean:

- `Amount`=484, `DecimalPlaces`=0 should Return "484"
- `Amount`=484, `DecimalPlaces`=1 should Return "48.4"
- `Amount`=484, `DecimalPlaces`=2 should Return "4.84"
- `Amount`=484, `DecimalPlaces`=3 should Return "0.484"
- `Amount`=484, `DecimalPlaces`=4 should Return "0.0484"
- `Amount`=484, `DecimalPlaces`=5 should Return "0.00484"
- ...

I have already an algorithm but I don't how to solve the leading zeros part.

This is my approach (I'm using golang btw):

```
func GetAmount(amount, places int) string {
    runes := []rune(strconv.Itoa(amount))
    result := ""
    for j := len(runes) - 1; j >= 0; j-- {
        result = string(runes[j]) + result
        if j == len(runes)-places {
            result = "." + result
        }
    }   
    return result
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use places to calculate a divider and a format string. See  https://play.golang.org/p/TjN4OrcDwy4

Comment: Great solution! tranks @Eelco

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May not be the most efficient, but here's a one-liner:

```
func GetAmount(amount, places int) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%.*f", places, float64(amount)/math.Pow10(places))
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/ppipUqX9eSF

**EDIT**: H/T to @perreal for one-liner suggestion!

Comment: Nice, +1 for using `math.Pow`. Much more elegant than mine.

Comment: @Eelco I bristled at using `math` at all...  checking the docs I discovered `Pow10`! Updated answer to reflect this optimization.

Comment: You can have a variable for the after dot precision: `return fmt.Sprintf("%.*f", places, float64(amount)/math.Pow10(places))`